# Small Claims Court jurisdiction over multi-property company

Tags: small-claims-court, jurisdiction

If I want to sue a Property Management company, that is domiciled in a different city and county from various properties they manage: Can I sue them in any city where they have property, or do I have to sue where they list their company address?

Comment: Is this in the U.S.?

Comment: List the city and state and we can probably point you to the applicable statute or court rule.

Comment: yes in the US, and its Oregon

Answer (score 2):

That would depend upon the state. However, most states would allow you to sue in a city where they do business.